# ArcPy: Geoprocessing for the data with specific variable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

Imagine if we have dataset like this:

```
+------+------------+
| City | DistrictID |
+------+------------+
|   A  |     001    |
+------+------------+
|   B  |     001    |
+------+------------+
|   C  |     002    |
+------+------------+
|   D  |     003    |
+------+------------+
|   E  |     003    |
+------+------------+
```

I would like to use geoprocessing tools for each district. For example, I would like to dissolve cities with respect to DistrictID (A and B will be dissolved and so on). Is it possible to conduct this kind of analysis using ArcPy?

Comment: Yes! What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I'm a Japanese user and I couldn't find any resources for this topic. Is there any support site that explains how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried [Google](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dissolve%20arcgis)? Or the all-knowing [ArcGIS resources](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. The answer to most "Is it possible" questions is almost always "Yes. What have you tried?" Coding questions are expected to contain code (an initial good-faith effort). Please always include the exact version of software in use.

Comment: As @Vince already said, you should be a bit more specific with your question. Maybe read about the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` function. It is very powerful and efficient. It allows you to subset your data so you can perform calculations etc on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `arcpy.Dissolve_management` tool.  See **[Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm)** on ArcGIS Desktop Help.

**Note: It will not output values from other fields**

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:/temp/SE/test.gdb" # Path to your feature class location

in_features = "TestFC" # Your Input feature class
out_feature_class = "TestFCOutput" # Name for your new output feature class

dissolve_field = "DistrictID" # Dissolves on this field

arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features, out_feature_class, dissolve_field, "", "SINGLE_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
```